# How to find max load limit in datasheet?

Tags: dc, datasheet, solid-state-relay, load

I have а [datasheet](http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1008N.pdf/$file/CPC1008N.pdf) but I don't understand: how to find max load limit in datasheet?

Can I use this SSR to switch the load (12V DC), and what current can I count on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum current through the output is listed in the datasheet:

[image]

So do not exceed 150 mA.

*But how can I get the maximum current for this temperature range?*

You can't. And you should not. Designing something so close to the edge is **asking for trouble**. What you need is **margin**, that means that you stay **far away** from that maximum current. So instead of going up to 150 mA or 120 mA (for 85 C) you should not exceed **50 mA**. Yes, that's a large margin.

But that should not be an issue if your load consumes less than 50 mA. If you have a load that needs more then **don't** use this switch to directly switch that load. Instead, use a relay of transistor to do the actual switching of the load. Relays for 12 V 50 mA can easily be found. Often such a relay can switch 2 A or more at 12 V or more. Problem solved.

Comment: Yes, but how does this value come from the ambient temperature?

Comment: It doesn't **come** from ambient temperature, it is **related to (ambient) temperature**. As the switch resistance is 8 ohm maximum at 150 mA that results in 1.2 V across the switch and 0.18 W power dissipation.That power will be dissipated as **heat**. If the ambient temperature is too high, the switch will **overheat** and might suffer **damage**. As the switch resistance increase with temperature, things get worse (more dissipation) at higher temperatures so that's why at 85C the current must be less than 120 mA.

Comment: Yes. This is my mistake in understanding.

Tell me, please, can I use a radiator to dissipate heat faster at high ambient temperatures?

Comment: Yes you can but that doesn't solve the root of the issue. Cooling the switch is "patch work" and not "proper engineering and design". If you need the switch to operate near its limits, you're **asking for trouble**. By that I mean: the switch might work for one month and then break. Do you want that? No, so instead: use a relay or transistor to do the actual switching.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But I was asked to use SSD in order not to configure Snubber to remove the EMI.

Can I connect two SSRs in parallel to increase the load power?

Comment: *Can I connect two SSRs in parallel to increase the load power?* That doesn't increase the load power, it increases the **maximum current**. In therory: yes you can. In practice I would never do that. Why? Because if one of the SSRs conducts better (due to slightly lower resistance) is will take more current and the SSRs don't divide the current equally. So again, it's **bad engineering**. If you need more current simply use a relay or transistor. I fail to understand why you insist on other solutions that are just "hacks".

Comment: I'm afraid to send EMI to a working device.

Comment: What makes you think that EMI will be an issue and why would it not be an issue when using an SSR? Sounds to me like the wrong reasons are used to avoid doing things "properly".

Comment: Good. I was a supporter of conventional electromagnetic relays. But then I began to read and study the theory of electronics. Then I found information is the relay contact closure creates an EMI, which causes damage to circuit components, such as an MCU.

Comment: You have fallen into the "*I read about this so it must be a problem so I must solve it*" pitfall. Yes, EMI can cause damage but only if you do the wrong things. An MCU needs to have supply decoupling capacitors, those will "eat up" any EMI disturbances from the relay contacts, also a relay needs a **flyback diode** at the coil to "eat up" back EMF, do that and: problem solved. You really should get some more **practical** insight in how things are build. Only studying the theory will make you believe **almost nothing** can actually work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - "the SSRs don't divide the current equally." Well, actually, one of the reasons MOSFETs are popular for power amplifiers is that they have a positive tempco for Rds. This means that, unlike BJTs they will tend to equalize current between parallel units, and do not suffer firecracker-mode failures. Usually. SSRs typically do use FETs, so your caution is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sure but there's no guarantee that discrete MOSFETs or the FETs in an SSR are in any way matched. If one is from a "somewhat low Rdson"  batch and the other is from a "somewhat high Rdson " batch the current will not be divided equally. Since there are solutions (higher rated SSR) to make a robust implementation I see no reason to use SSRs in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EE.SE.  The short answer to your question is right at the top of the datasheet:

[image]

The blocking voltage is the voltage the switch can sustain when open, and the load current is the maximum current the switch can handle when closed.

Note that these are the 'headline' specs, and are the general best-case specifications the manufacturer has chosen to highlight.  For a more complete answer, you'll need to determine the maximum allowable power dissipation given your operating conditions (in particular, ambient temperature).

This is done by taking the package thermal resistance in combination with the allowable maximum die temperature minus your ambient temperature.  Then you can divide this by the on-resistance, take the square root, and that's your allowable current

Comment: Yes, ambient temperature is my problem:

I want to use this relay outdoors, that is, from -30 ... -35 ° C (in winter) to + 40 ° C (in summer).

Answer (score 1):

What you do is go to page R11, and look at the upper right graph, which shows the maximum load current vs. temperature.

Comment: Excuse me. @Bimpelrekkie helped me to understand the essence correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Information from the datasheet is fairly clear.*

150 mA RMS which is the continuous rating and 350 mA peak.

Note that the on-resistance can be up to 8 Ω and at 150 mA the power dissipation will be \$ I^2 R = 0.15^2 \times 8 = 0.18 \ W\$. That appears to be well within the 400 mW limit specified in the top table.

For your 12 V supply this means that the minimum resistance you can drive is \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {12}{0.15} = 80 \ \Omega \$.

Comment: For "fairly clear": how does this value come from the ambient temperature?

Comment: What value are you asking about?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie explained to me his mistake in understanding. Now I just want to clarify, is it possible to connect two SSRs in parallel to increase the load power?